# Для чего нужны файлы устройств?

Tags: linux, c, драйвер

Чтобы использовать `символьный драйвер` - нам надо создать `файл устройста`, он же `специальный файл` или `узел дерева файловой системы`. У меня есть два мнения для чего он нужен, скажите, пожалуйста, какое правильное (если есть такое).

1) Это файл, который служит неким интерфейсом. Например, когда мы пишем такую команду `echo "hello" > /dev/my_driver`, то строка `"hello"` пишется не в сам файл `/dev/my_driver`, а в некий буфер, который нам предоставляет ядро. Так-же с функциями `open`, `read` и тд., они не открывают сам файл, а просто сигнализируют, что надо создать и открыть некий файл или прочитать данные.

2) Это обычный файл, в который мы записываем данные и читаем их оттуда же. При той же команде `echo "hello" > /dev/my_driver`, строка `"hello"` запишется непосредственно в файл `/dev/my_driver`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Правильный вариант, скорее, — (1); чтение/запись обрабатывается непосредственно драйвером устройства, промежуточного буфера может и не быть (хотя обычно он есть в пространстве ядра).

#### Что вообще происходит при вызовах `open()`/`read()` итд?

При системном вызове [`open()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.5/source/fs/open.c#L1048) в массив файловых дескрипторов (`current->files->fdt->fd`), связанный со структурой текущего работающего процесса (`current`), помещается новая запись ([`struct fd`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.5/source/include/linux/file.h#L33)), которая содержит структуру отождествляемую с открытым файлом ([`struct file`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.5/source/include/linux/fs.h#L907)). При этом в поле данной структуры `f_op` записывается набор операций, которые можно делать с данным файлом ([`struct file_operations`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.5/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1789)). В итоге вызов `open()` просто возвращает номер новой выделенной записи в вышеупомянутом массиве.

Вызов [`read()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.5/source/fs/read_write.c#L571) по сути просто достаёт файловых дескриптор из массива с помощью [`fdgetpos()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.5/source/include/linux/file.h#L68), [проверяет](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.5/source/fs/read_write.c#L445) права доступа на чтение/запись и [вызывает](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.5/source/fs/read_write.c#L416) уже заданную связанную с файлом операцию чтения.

Аналогично работают и все прочие вызовы — `write`/`mmap`/`ioctl` итп.

#### Так чем же отличается чтение из обычного файла и из файла-устройства?

По сути ни чем: единственное различие в том, что набор операций (`struct files_struct`) при открытии берётся не от драйвера файловой системы, а от драйвера устройства. Аналогичным образом реализованы и файлы в псевдо-файловых-cистемах `/proc` и `/sys`.

Comment: Перед каждым вызовом read/write происходит вызов функции open(). Подскажите, пожалуйста, каждый ли раз приходится выполнять цикл для функции open() (в массив файловых дескрипторов помещается новая запись struct fd -> возвращается номер новой выделенной записи в массиве) или всего один раз при первом открытии файла ?

Comment: @Антон, при каждом, какого-либо скрытого кеширования тут нет, если ты об этом... соответственно, если не делать `close()`, которая собственно закрывает дескриптор, то легко получить исчерпание по оным (на большинстве современных linux систем обычно по умолчанию лимит установлен в 4096)... Кстати, иногда важный момент, что `open()` всегда выделяет наименьший свободный дескриптор...

Answer (score 4):

Если говорить о файлах устройств (есть ещё и другие псевдофайлы), то отличие их от обычных ("регулярных") файлов заключается в том, что:

- регулярные файлы существуют в физической реальности. После записи байта в такой файл мы можем найти место в физическом мире, где этот байт лежит.
- псевдофайлы (в том числе и файлы устройств) физически не существуют. После записи байта в файл */dev/ttys0* этот байт не присутствует нигде в реальном мире.

Совершенно аналогичная ситуация с псевдофайлами из каталогов /proc, /sys и т.д. Запись в эти файлы (при наличии прав доступа) приводит к измению поведения ОС, а вовсе не к тому, что записанный (якобы) байт где-то сохранился.

Несколько особая ситуация с псевдофайлами устройств дисковых накопителей. Хотя для /dev/sda1 можно выполнять операции чтения/записи, вот только результат будет довольно неожиданный, так как операции ввода/вывода будут выполняться не с файлами (расположенными ВНУТРИ диска), а с блоками, образующими ФС этого диска.

Совершенно особая песня - псевдофайлы сетевых карточек, разделяемой памяти и т.д. которые используются исключительно для управления этими устройствами, а операции ввода/вывода выполняются специальными IOCTL командами, образующими систему сокетов.

Короче - это всё сложная и большая тема.